# SQL : Retrieve ID stored in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a bit lost about how to retrieve the Id. I have stored inside a string like

`Hi i am interested in sharing apartment or to rent all rooms please text me {PropertyId:43499}`

The part I want from this is `43499`

How can I achieve this in my Sql-Server.

The solution that worked for me, i edited the answer i got from Kavin Chakaravarthi

```
DECLARE @string nvarchar(max)
SET @string = 'Hi i am interested in sharing apartment or to rent all rooms please text me {PropertyId:43499}'
select SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@string, CHARINDEX(':',@string) +1, DATALENGTH(@string)), 0,6)`
```

Comment: More samples are needed, also table structures with sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SQL Query u can get the seperate id:

```
 declare @id varchar(max)='Hi i am interested in sharing apartment or to rent all rooms please text me {PropertyId:43499}'
 select @id=STUFF(@id,LEN(@id),1,'')
 select @id=SUBSTRING(@id,CHARINDEX(':',@id)+1,LEN(@id))
 select @id
```

Output:

```
 id
43499
```

Comment: Thanks just the solution I was looking for!

Comment: Aren't you assuming that the ID is always the last part of the message? What would happen if the text was as in the question with an ending }?

Comment: @Matt yeah i saw that, and thanks for taking the time to answer me question. But in my case, the Id is always in the end of the string :)

Comment: @athobe Just to be fair, the answer you accepted is not responding correctly to the question you asked ...

Comment: @Simone that is correct, there will always be a curly bracket at the end. I Modified the answer to fit my issue.  let me add the solution to me question

Comment: I thought so i have to separate from PropertyId:43499.lets seethe modified ans

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.propertyidextract
(@strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @intAlpha INT
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
BEGIN
WHILE @intAlpha > 0
BEGIN
SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric )
END
END
RETURN ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric,0)
END
GO

SELECT dbo.propertyidextract(phrase) AS 'propertyid'
FROM yourtable;
GO
```

This outputs your ID

```
propertyid
43499
```

SQL FIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4c22f/12/0

Answer (score 0):

if using C#,

you can take the last N text from the String(if the ID is always at the end of String) and remove all char other than digit(if the ID is always digit) by using `SubString`

if using sql-server

you can use `SubString` too, this is the sample how to use it

http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/substring.php

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your exact scenario, you'll need to build upon it if your search string is in different formats.

```
declare @x varchar(100) = 'blah blah blah {PropertyId:43499}'
SELECT RIGHT(@x, LEN(@x) - CHARINDEX(':', @x))
SELECT LEFT(@x, LEN(@x) - 1)
/* or LEFT(@x, LEN(@x) - CHARINDEX('}', @x)) */
```